How to submit data split into multiple children components without unnecessary re-renders
The challenge I'm facing in my React project is about submitting data that is split into multiple children.
Basically, I'm developing a recipe app, and I have the sub-root component RecipeCreator. This parent component renders some children components, deputed to collect the infos from the user to create a recipe to be stored in the database. The children all have different duties: one is deputed to ask the user for a recipe image, another one handles the "body" of the recipe, another one takes care of gathering the ingredients required.
Each one of them is quite complex, since for example the IngredientsSelector implements a logic to generate accordions based on the ingredients the user chooses, implementing an autocomplete mechanism based on the already existing ingredients on the DB and such; the RecipeEditor implements a custom react-quill text editor, and so on.
Now, after coding and testing such children components, I'm clueless on what's the best approach to put together all the pieces and send the infos to the database.
I'm thinking about three different approaches:

Declare a single / multiple state in the parent component (RecipeCreator), with a complex data structure tha should store all the data from the children, and pass the state setters appropriately to each child component. The button "Submit" is placed in the parent's logic, therefore it just needs to create an object from the big state objects (or multiple states) and call the POST API. I'm very dubious about this, because each time a child changes its state, the parent captures the change and re-renders, re-rendering all the children. While I can wrap the children in a React.Memo wrapper, I don't think this is the best solution. Take for example the "extreme case" of the child RecipeEditor. The react-quill input is controlled by the state, and each keystroke would end up triggering a re-render of the component plus the parent, since the latter provided the state setter to get what's been typed.

Make use of the Redux store I already implemented: not only I find unnecessary to store all the infos the user is typing into the store, but the problem of the parent's re-rendering after each keystroke would still be present, because it needs to subscribe to that piece of the store with a useSelector() hook that would in fact act very similarly to the state setter passed through props to the children as discussed previously.

Putting a "save changes" button in each child component, so the parent would see the edits only if the user clicked on the save button in each section (ingredients component, recipe editor component, image uploader component...). While this could work to cut out unnecessary re-renders, I don't like the style of this approach and I'm not a fan of multiple "save" buttons in the same page / forms.



For the third option consider using refs:
export interface A {
  a: string
}

export interface B {
  b: string
}

export default function Parent() {
  const ref1: MutableRefObject<A> = useRef({a: ""})
  const ref2: MutableRefObject<B> = useRef({b: ""})

  const handleConfirm = () => {
    const a = ref1.current.a
    const b = ref2.current.b
    const ab = {a, b}
    // send combined data
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <BlockA ref={ref1}/>
      <BlockB ref={ref2}/>
      <button onClick={handleConfirm}/>
    </div>
  )
}

// BlockA and BlockB are similar

export interface BlockAProps {
  ref: MutableRefObject<A>
}

export default function BlockA(p: BlockAProps) {
  const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    p.ref.current.a = e.currentTarget.value
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={handleChange}/>
    </div>
  )
}


Second option gives the ability to render children separately as they listen to the store updates, not props. This way you'll have more fine-grained control over re-rendering inter-dependent child components (e.g. highlighting an ingredient mentioned in the recipe steps, when clicked in the list).
First option is kind of similar to redux solution (as you'll have single source of true) + you deal with re-renders. Yes you'll have to use memo technique.
Try also useDeferredValue for handling keystrokes.
If the scaling and maintaining in a long run is a concern, I would stick to second solution.
